# How to get IEnumerable<Foo> instead of IEnumerable<string> from LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am stuck on a LINQ query where I have being trying to return a list records from an `SQL Table` using `EntityFramework 6`, instead of getting that list, I keep end up getting an `IEnumerable<string[]>`.

This is what I have made to get `IEnumerable<string[]>`. I have an `column` in the `table` that needs to be split and then I test to see if a `list` contains those strings  : The value in the table column `columnOne` can be something like this `"a-b"` or `"b-c"` etc, hence the need to use this `s.columnOne.Split('-')`

```
list<string> checkList = new list<string>();
checkList.add("a")
checkList.add("b")
checkList.add("c")

List<Foo> fooList = dbContext.Foos.ToList();

IEnumerable<string[]> items = fooList.Select(s => s.columnOne.Split('-'));

var result = items.SelectMany(x => x)
                  .Where(s => checkList.Contains(s)).ToList();
```

The above works as it should, but in the end it returns a list of `string`, which is not what I need.

I tried this below:

```
List<Foo> fooList = dbContext.Foos.ToList();

var test = fooList.Where(s => s.columnOne.Split('-'));
```

And this is where I run into the error and can go no further as I am ultimately trying to return a list of `<Foo>`, not `<string>`

Now I know that the `Where` clause needs to return a `bool` value such as `fooList.Where(s => s.columnOne == "someString");`, but I am at a loss as to how to go about structuring the LINQ query to get the results I am trying to get.

Any shove in the right direction would be great.

Comment: why do you need to `Split()` to check of presence of character ? if you have astring "a-b-c" , `Contains("a")` will still be positive .

Comment: Write a method that has your custom logic that returns a bool.  Then call that from your query: `fooList.Where(s => CheckIfContains(s.columnOne, "a"));`

Comment: ``fooList.Where(s => s.columnOne.Split('-').Any(x => checkList.Contains(x));``

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you expect it to be ``IEnumerable<Foo>`` in the first place? You are expliciting telling that ``fooList.Select(s => s.columnOne.Split('-'));`` what line of code of yours did you think would do the "unselect"?

Comment: @RandRandom, I wasn't expecting it to be `IEnumerable<Foo>`, that is what I was working towards, but anything that I got to compile correctly was always an `IEnumerable<string>`. I knew that the `select` would always return a `string` from that `column` and that is the obvious reason why I was stuck on doing this using the `Where` clause. Cheers

Comment: @Tigran also, in my actual data I am having to split fairly long strings, I just used the chars as a simple example. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The where clause needs to contain the check against the `checkList`

```
var test = fooList.Where(foo => foo.columnOne.Split('-').Any(str => checkList.Contains(str)));
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. I never knew you could structure the query like that. Learnt a lot today. Thanks!!!

Comment: @KyloRen - you can write "everything" the only requirement it needs is that it returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
dbContext.Foos
    .ToList()
    .Where(foo => foo.columnOne.Split('-')
        .Any(x => checkList.Contains(x))
```

I hope you don't ever have very many `Foo`s because that `ToList` function will read them all into memory.  You'll need that, though, because I don't think Linq can understand how to translate that `where` statement.  There are a few ways to get around that, if it's a problem to you.

Also, consider using a `Set<string>` instead of a `List<string>` for your `checklist` variable, as it'll perform better for membership checks like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the extra advice, very much appreciated.